# Clojure applying a map and keyword arguments destruction

Tags: dictionary, clojure, keyword-argument, destruction

Consider a function with the following signature:

```
(defn make-widget [& {:keys [x y] :or {x 10 y 20}}]
 ...)
```

What is the best way to pass a map to the function, e.g.:

```
(make-widget {:x 100})
```

or

```
(make-widget {:y 200 :x 0})
```

What I have currently thought of is via `vec`, `flatten` and `apply` e.g.:

```
(apply make-widget (flatten (vec ({:x 100}))
```

I strongly believe there is a better way to do this. Can you please consider one?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can't think of a more elegant way, either, though it seems to me to that there should be one (like a map-specific variant of `apply`).

Using `flatten` has problems beyond not being very elegant, though. If the values of your map are collections, `flatten` will work recursively on those, too, so things could get totally mixed up. This alternative avoids that problem:

```
(apply make-widget (apply concat {:x 100}))
```

Comment: The mapply function, described in noncom's answer, is the standard way to do this.

Answer (score 8):

There is also a known (not invented by me at least), function "mapply":

```
(defn mapply [f & args] (apply f (apply concat (butlast args) (last args))))
```

which can be applied like

```
(mapply your-function {:your "map"})
```

As to why is this language-specific functionality absent from Clojure core, being implemented more natively and elegantly, no one could ever give me a clear answer.

**UPDATE**

After I have spent much time programming in Clojure, I personally tend to refrain from creating functions that accept a `{}` as a vararg. Although at first this can seem appealing, in reality experience proves that passing an explicit `{}` is always better for many reasons.

Comment: The ubiquitous mapply has been helpfully packaged up for us at https://github.com/ToBeReplaced/mapply . Just add [org.tobereplaced/mapply "1.0.0"] to your project.clj dependencies.

Answer (score 7):

You can use:

```
(apply make-widget (mapcat identity {:x 200 :y 0}))
```